# Django. Why do these urls conflict?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm wondering why these urls conflict with each other.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^editar_perfil/$', views.editar_perfil, name="editar_perfil"),

url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w.]+)/$', views.perfil_usuario, name="perfil_usuario"),
url(r'^leyendo_libro_ajax/$', views.leyendo_libro_ajax, name="leyendo_libro_ajax"),
```

So, if I place the urls like that I can't get to the url named `leyendo_libro_ajax`, it goes to the url called `perfil_usuario`. BUT if I try to go to the url `editar_perfil`(the first one), it correctly lands on the `editar_perfil` view. Why? If this isn't a bug, please help me understand.

Comment: You need to show us how do you code up the urls in your template.

Comment: i think, if you pass the perfil_usuario url, to below leyendo_libro_ajax, it should work.

Comment: knbk's answer is correct. however, On a side note, `-\w,` is the equivalent of just a `.` - if you want to match dots in the regex, you have to escape it like this: `-\w\.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django tries each pattern in the defined order, and returns the first view where the url matches the regex. The url for your last view, `/leyendo_libro_ajax/`, also matches the regex for your `perfil_usuario` view. Since that's the first match, that's the view that Django uses.

To have these views coexist, you need to move the last view up above the second view:

```
url(r'^editar_perfil/$', views.editar_perfil, name="editar_perfil"),
url(r'^leyendo_libro_ajax/$', views.leyendo_libro_ajax, name="leyendo_libro_ajax"),
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w.]+)/$', views.perfil_usuario, name="perfil_usuario"),
```

This way, `editar_perfil` and `leyendo_libro_ajax` will always be the first match for their respective urls, but any other url will still match the regex for `perfil_usuario`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.